# Codeblocks : "Error creating process (error 193) " with SDL2

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, codeblocks, sdl-2

I want to debug a code with codeblocks. It is not possible if I use the SDL2 lib.

The building of the bin/debug/*.exe is ok...but when I run it there is the following message:

```
Starting debugger: gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args .../bin/Debug/dsl2_test4.exe
done
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
Error creating process ...\bin\Debug\dsl2_test4.exe, (error 193).
Debugger finished with status 0
```

It appears when I add `#include <SDL.h>`

Has someone an idea to solve my problem because I would like to debug complex code using SDL2...

example of code:

```cpp
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL.h>   

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 int a;
 int b = 5;
 a = b+6;
 return 0;
}
```

I want to run a debug *.exe with "#include <SDL.h>"

---

edit 1

---

build log is :

```
-------------- Clean: Debug in dsl2_test4 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Cleaned "dsl2_test4 - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in dsl2_test4 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -Wall -g -I..\SDL2\SDL2-devel-2.24.0-mingw\SDL2-2.24.0\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 -c ...\dsl2_test4\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
g++.exe -LC:\SDL2\SDL2-devel-2.24.0-mingw\SDL2-2.24.0\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -o bin\Debug\dsl2_test4.exe obj\Debug\main.o   -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2.dll -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -ldxguid
\dsl2_test4\main.cpp: In function 'int SDL_main(int, char**)':
\dsl2_test4\main.cpp:11:9: warning: variable 'a' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int a;
         ^
Output file is bin\Debug\dsl2_test4.exe with size 85.52 KB
Running project post-build steps
XCOPY ...\SDL2\SDL2-devel-2.24.0-mingw\SDL2-2.24.0\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\*.dll bin\Debug\ /D /Y
0 fichier(s) copi‚(s)
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
0 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

(I have manually copied SDL2.dll in bin/debug)

---

Compiler and Debugger settings are

Debugger settings -> GDB/CDB debugger -> Default : excutable path : C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe

Compiler settings ->Debugger : GDB/CDB debugger : Default

---

Comment: Make sure the SDL DLL files are in the same directory as the executable and they are the proper version, 64 or 32 bit, to match the application.

Comment: Error `193` is `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` which means either your program or the one of the DLL's it uses is not a valid executable/DLL file.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to tell (and show?) exactly how you build your program (for example copy-paste the full and complete verbose build-log into the question)? What is your configuration for building (flags, libraries, etc.)?

Comment: I use "codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup" that includes GDB debugger from MinGW-W64 project (version 8.1.0, 32/64 bit,SEH) and SDL2-devel-2.24.0-mingw

Comment: SDL2.dll is in the same directoty as the executable. And the .exe runs in debug mode without "#include <SDL.h>"

Comment: on the console the error 193 appears with  :  (gdb) run

Answer (score 0):

looking at other forums, the problem is solved : I add "#undef main" after "#include <SDL.h>"

Comment: Not solved, postponed. Once you try to use SDL functionality you'll have two problems, the original and the one that `#undef main` causes.